# :not() not working as expected

Tags: css

Are there any limitations in using the `:not()` operator?

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>AAAAAAA</th>
        <th>VVVVVVVVVVV</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>111111</td>
        <td>22222</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table class="t">
    <thead>
        <th>AAAAAAA</th>
        <th>VVVVVVVVVVV</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>111111</td>
        <td>22222</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this CSS:

```
table td:not(.t) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding-left: 5px;
          }


table th:not(.t) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding-left: 5px;
          }
```

Yet both tables get the CSS rules.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4uvY/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `.t` is applied to a `table` not a `td`

Try this:

```
table:not(.t) td
{
    ...
}
```

---

```
table:not(.t) td, table:not(.t) th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Just noticed, you can group your declarations too since they're the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand now what I was doing wrong. Not sure why I'm getting downvoted though

Comment: No worries. The way I think of it is "pick every table that is not `.t`"

Answer (score 1):

You're having that class for a table, not any other element. So instead of applying it to the `td` apply it to `table` it would work.